# Do you know a similar program for watch (unix watch command) on Windows?

Tags: windows, unix

I find unxutils and and gnuwin32 Packages don't have this command...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On systems where I don't have a `watch`, I often use an infinite loop (you could also write it as an alias)

I'm using Bash syntax here, but you can surely do something similar on your platform:

```
while true; do my-thing-to-watch; sleep 1; done
```

And, for convenience, one can wrap it into a command which reuses either $0 or $@ depending on your platform.

Comment: It's useful in my situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Lee's answer works for Bash, but for Windows, create a file watch.bat and put it in any PATH folder:

```
for /l %%g in () do @( %* & timeout /t 5)
```